# How does numpy zeros implement the parameter shape?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to implement a similar function, and want to accept an array or number that I pass to `numpy.ones`.

Specifically, I want to do this:

```
def halfs(shape):
    shape = numpy.concatenate([2], shape)
    return 0.5 * numpy.ones(shape)
```

Example input-output pairs:

```
# default
In [5]: beta_jeffreys()
Out[5]: array([-0.5, -0.5])

# scalar
In [5]: beta_jeffreys(3)
Out[3]: 
array([[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5],
       [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5]])

# vector (1)
In [3]: beta_jeffreys((3,))
Out[3]: 
array([[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5],
       [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5]])

# vector (2)
In [7]: beta_jeffreys((2,3))
Out[7]: 
array([[[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5],
        [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5]],

       [[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5],
        [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5]]])
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more what you would like to accomplish?

Comment: You give your function a shape and you want to add one dimension (2) to it and fill with 0.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def halfs(shape=()):
    if isinstance(shape, tuple):
        return 0.5 * numpy.ones((2,) + shape)
    else:
        return 0.5 * numpy.ones((2, shape))



a = numpy.arange(5)
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])


halfs(a.shape)
#array([[ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
#       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5]])

halfs(3)
#array([[ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
#       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5]])
```

Comment: I have now edited it and made shape optional, as you stated in your comment. So you can call it with `halfs()` and it will return a 1-dimensional array of two 0,5 elements.

Comment: This looks good when shape is an array, but this doesn't work with ints.  How does numpy accept arrays or scalars?

Comment: @Neil, you have to write an example in your original question with example input and output.

Comment: @Neil, I think I understand what you mean and I have edited it now along with examples. However, this is not very clean way to go and it makes your code more difficult to debug.

Comment: @eumiro, thank you very much.  this is exactly what I was looking for.  Presumably, numpy.ones does a similar test for tuple-ness internally?